# discrete quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Given a process $X$, consider:

$$<X>_{\pi}(t)= \sum_{k=1}^n |X(t_k \wedge t)- X(t_{k-1})|^2$$ for $t \in [0,T]$ and the partition $\pi$ of $ [0,T]$

I wonder why the discrete quadratic variation is not increasing,since we are adding only positive summands in each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about $t \in [0,t_1]$, then $\langle X \rangle_\pi(t) = |X(t)-X(0)|^2$, and there is no reason this should be increasing.  It is certainly increasing along $t_1, t_2, ..., t_n$, but doesn't need to be increasing between the partition points.

Comment: But I square each increment so the sum must get larger?

Comment: I think I miss something important.

Comment: You aren't adding any additional terms to the sum when $t$ moves between $t_k$ and $t_{k+1}$.  For example, if $t_1=1$ and $X(0)=0$, then for $t \in [0,1]$ we have $\langle X \rangle_\pi(t) = |X(t)-X(0)|^2 = |X(t)|^2$.  There is no reason that $|X(\frac 34)|^2$ must be greater than $|X(\frac 12)|^2$.